# llamado Servicio API solo funciona una vez , segunda llamada del servicio da error 1001 - usando AlamoFire en SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

programando en Xcode una aplicacion que llama unos servicios nuevos. El llamado de otros servicios funcionan normalmente pero el llamado de otros Servicio Rest de otro servidor  solo funciona una vez usando Xcode y Emulador de Iphone,luego  haciendo una segunda llamada del mismo servicio GET da error 1001 y tiempo de espera. Debo borrar la aplicación del emulador para poder realizar nuevamente el llamado de la misma API.

algún error ? algo me falta??

todo es lenguaje: Swift , uso de ViewController , IOS.

```
import Alamofire

class MediosRemEntity {
    func getCardForOne(userId: String,  completionHandler: @escaping ([CardOneList]?, String?) -> Void){
        let parameters: Parameters = [:]

        services.requestJSONeWalletOne(userId: userId,endpointName: "getCard", method: .get, params : parameters) { response in
            do {
                     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                     let data = try decoder.decode(CardOneClick.self, from: response)

                     guard let internalCode = data.internalCode else {
                        let emptyCardList : [CardOneList] = []
                        completionHandler(emptyCardList, nil)
                        return
                    }
                    if internalCode == "200-0"{
                     guard let cardResult : [CardOneList]  = data.payload.cards else {
                            let emptyCardList : [CardOneList] = []
                           completionHandler(emptyCardList, nil)
                            return
                        }
                     completionHandler(cardResult,nil)
                    }else{
                        guard let message = data.message else {
                            let emptyCardList : [CardOneList] = []
                            completionHandler(emptyCardList, nil)
                            return
                        }
                        let emptyCardList : [CardOneList] = []
                        completionHandler(emptyCardList, message)
                    }
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let emptyCardList : [CardOneList] = []
                completionHandler(emptyCardList, nil)
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

```
import Alamofire
import CodableAlamofire

open class API{
public func requestJSONeWalletOne(userId: String,endpointName: String, method: HTTPMethod, params: [String : Any]? = nil, callback: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {
        var headers: [String: String] = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
        let endpointData = getEndpoint(fromName: endpointName)!
        headers["x-api-key"] = endpointData.APIKey
        if let APIToken = endpointData.APIToken {
            headers["x-api-token"] = APIToken
        }

        let urlhttp = endpointData.url.absoluteString + userId

        Alamofire.request(urlhttp, method: method, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseData { (response) in
            callback(response.data ?? Data())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Te sucede lo mismo si llamas con Postman a ese servicio? Porque si el llamado de unos servicios funcionan bien y hay uno que te da falla entonces algo debe estar ese servicio.

Comment: en post funciona perfecto , llamando desde android funciona perfecto , de IOS con swift funciona los servicios antiguos bien , pero este llamado a otro servidor API funciona solo una Vez , lista perfecto , pero llamandolo en pruebas en la app al mismo servicio nuevamente da tiempo de espera y error 1001 ,como que permite llamarlo solo una vez pero llamandolo nuevamente da ese error, debo borrar la app del emulador y ahi funciona , pero vuelve el mismo tema de error 1001 en pruebas.

Comment: Quiero entender, si imprimes el response del request, ese response te da 1001?

Answer (score 0):

Según el problema que detallas puede ser esto:

Puedes cambiar esta línea :

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(), headers: headers)
```

po esta:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(), headers: headers)
```

La mayoría de servidores soporta `URLEncoding` y no `JSONEncoding` aunque puede enviar la data. Debes revisar en tu servidor si soporta el envío del `httpBody` por `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Estimados se soluciono el problema de latencia y rellamado de servicio, todo tiene que ver con el servidor y sus restricciones de backend , cuando se cambio de url y servidor todo mejoro y no hay latencia , cuando les aparezca un  error 1001 de parte de IOS en sus simuladores de xcode reclame directamente a el desarrollador del backend por si tiene alguna restricción que impida libre comunicación entre su dispositivo y el servidor rest tambien revisen su usuario y VPN.

**nota: no olviden que el llamado desde de IOs xcode a la api es muy distinta al llamado que hace postman a la api por si lo usan como excusa los backend.**

Atte y gracias por su ayuda a uds.